# IE8 is rendering in unknown document and browser mode

Tags: performance, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, ie-developer-tools

I have a Strict doctype and a X-UA-Compatible meta tag and yet, anytime I load this page I'm developing, it renders in "Unknown" Document and Browser mode. Any solutions and/or ideas?

P.S: I'm running locally.[image]
This is after the page has rendered completely.

[image]

Comment: Has the page completely loaded at the time you're checking? (And are there any rendering problems?)

Comment: The page loads completely, but I'm not able to view any of the source (i.e html, css and js.) Kind of hampers my ability to develop with backwards compatibility in mind haha. No rendering issues, either. In fact, it looks _too good_

Comment: Perhaps there is a *ridiculous* header sent back?

Comment: It could be usual IE8 bugginess, too. Try IE9 in IE8 mode for compatibility testing if possible.

Comment: I'd remove all content from the `<body>` and `<head>` except the meta tag and the doctype, and check if the issue persists...

Comment: Oh - what's in your `X-UA-Compatible` tag?

Comment: Do you have any script that are in an infinite loop or something? :D And how long have you tried waiting? It can take a very long time to load the Developer Tools on occasion.

Comment: Added another screenshot with contents of htmlBegin.jsp page. I've had it open for hours at one point haha. And no, not that I'm aware of. But, you never know when working with a large team.

Comment: @Šime Vidas Interestingly enough, it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I feel like an idiot. Turns out it was the ChromeFrame plug-in. Didn't realize it was bundled with IE on Microsoft's site. Unfortunately, you have to completely remove it from your system, rather than just disable it.

Comment: The31StReaper, you really saved me a lot of head banging against the wall. Thank you.

Comment: Hey, no problem. It was quite the pain and I'm glad I could help someone else out.

Comment: This was my problem as well. I have only see it cause a conflict with the same ActiveX control on 2 of many computers of a similar configuration. It is unfortunate because I need to have ChromeFrame on the computer plus the control on another page. I sure thought ChromeFrame was supposed to avoid affecting pages that did not ask for it.

*Note* - Also, in both cases I was able to correct the issue by simply disabling "ChromeFrame BHO" and restarting the browser.

Comment: @TheHerk Thanks for that note, I wasn't aware of that at the time.